# I'm having issues with finding the right nvidia drivers for Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 19.04

I have:
32GB DDR4 RAM
3TB Seagate Barracuda
2TB Seagate Barracuda
500GB Samsung 860Evo
ASUS Prime B350-Plus
AMD Ryzen 5 1600X
Nvidia GTX 1060

When I enable basically any nvidia driver in the software and drivers menu.
Ubuntu loads then brings me to the Ubuntu loading screen in what looks like 800x600 and then it goes to black with the Ubuntu loading animation(the little dots and just the dots). When I load into advanced settings, it just loads the Gnome Display manager and then just gets stuck.

Please tell me if I need to provide anymore information.

Comment: DId you tried something like [`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-drivers?sort=votes&pageSize=15)?

Answer (score 2):

Try booting in advanced mode. Then on the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to a tty. On there log in with your user and run `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` or select the Nvidia driver manually via `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430` (use 2x <kbd>Tab</kbd> to to autocomplete the package selection and choose the newest one).

If you're on wifi and have to connect first use the `nmcli` utity: `nmcli device wifi connect "your ssid" password "your pw"`